$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sum_{k,j=0}^{n} a_k\bar{a_j}R^{n+k+j}e^{(n+k-j)i\theta} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}a_0\bar{a_n}R^{2n}d\theta$
I saw the expression $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{k,j=0}^{n} a_k\overline{a_j}R^{n+k+j}e^{(n+k-j)i\theta} d\theta = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}a_0\overline{a_n}R^{2n}d\theta$, where R is a real positive number. How can we arrive at the RHS from the LHS? One comment that was made to justify this expression was that the complex exponential function is $2\pi$ periodic, but I'm just not seeing how we get the equality.

Note that
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{mi\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert\zeta\rvert=1}\zeta^{m-1}\,\mathrm d\zeta=\begin{cases}
1,&m=0,\\
0,&m\neq0,
\end{cases}$$
by the Residue theorem. Now just integrate termwise and apply the above.
